# Solving an ODE with non-local coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the function $y$ that satisfies
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{\int_0 ^1 y dx}, \quad y(0)=3
$$
Since the denominator is constant, I guess the solution is
$$
y=3e^{\frac{x}{\int_0 ^1 y dx}}
$$
but it doesn't make sense, because I am still left with an integral involving $y$ in the exponent...

So, how can I solve such an equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y(x)=ce^{\lambda{x}}$, plug this into the equation to give
$$c=\frac{1}{e^{\lambda}-1}$$
Hence
$$\lambda=\ln\Big(\frac{1}{c}+1\Big)$$
$$y(0)=3$$
Thus
$$c=3$$
and
$$\lambda=\ln\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)$$
and
$$y(x)=3e^{\ln\big(\frac{4}{3}\big)x}=3e^{\ln\big(\frac{4^{x}}{3^{x}}\big)}=\frac{4^{x}}{3^{x-1}}$$

Comment: Great ! Many thanks !

Comment: (+1) Good choice. With $y=\alpha\beta^x$ you will find $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=\dfrac43$.