# Solving ODE with non-local term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I want to ask a similar question as found here: [Solving an ODE with non-local coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393161/solving-an-ode-with-non-local-coefficient). Except my ODE is slightly more complicated because the integral is not constant over $x$. Consider this equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x) = \left(1 - \int_0^xy(x')dx'\right)y(x)$$

If necessary, the solution only has to exist on an interval, say $[0,1]$. Is there any way to attack this analytically? The question I linked only has one answer which is just to guess a solution. What if we change $y$ into $y = \frac{dz}{dx}$ and then break up the definite integral? I think we get,

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} = \left(1 - z(x) + z(0)\right)\frac{dz}{dx}$$

So now we just have to deal with that $z(0)$. If we assume we know $z(0)$, it's possible to get a solution (e.g. if it's some constant, the solution is fairly simple). What if we don't know?

Comment: This is not an ODE anymore, it's an integro-differential equation

Comment: @Yuriy S Ah, there's the keyword I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @ HiddenBabel, you are welcome. It's quite an interesting area of maths, with lots of applications. It might be that your case could be reduced to an ODE though.

Comment: You can fix $z(0)=0$ by setting $z=\int_0^x y$ instead of just any antiderivative of $y$.  So you want to solve $z''=(1-z)z'$ which is easy enough to reduce to a Riccati equation.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh that's good. Unfortunately the real equation I want to solve also has a $\int_x^1y term. Would that trick happen to work twice?

Comment: If both $\int_0^x y$ and $\int_x^1 y$ appears, then you need the constant $\lambda=\int_0^1 y$ as well, so $\int_x^1 y=\lambda-\int_0^x y=\lambda-z$, etc.  Assuming you can solve the equation $f(x,z,z',z'',\dots)=0$ for $z$, you only need to solve for $z(1)=\lambda$ and recover $y=z'$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks! So just to be clear, I solve for $z$ which comes with 2 constants, $c_1$ and $c_2$. I can solve for these using $z(0)=0$ and $z(1)=\lambda$. Then I can differentiate to get $y$?